# Is it true that the mysql extension of PHP doesn't support Transactions with "FOR UPDATE"?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, mysqli

If I use the following code my "row lock" works fine:

```
mysqli_query($link, 'START TRANSACTION');
mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM '. $table .' WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE');
```

Unforunatly my server doesn't support "mysqli". Is it true that the following (with "mysql") doesn't work?

```
mysql_query($link, 'START TRANSACTION');
mysql_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM '. $table .' WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE');
```

Is there a workaround?
Thanks

Comment: It's true that you can test it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

OK - If I use

```
mysql_query('START TRANSACTION', $link);...
```

instead of

```
mysql_query($link, 'START TRANSACTION');...
```

it works.